# Kendo nested grid to save all at once

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have nested grid in kendo and I'm using the batch editing process in which all changes on the given row, which is which the parent row or the sub row will be saved all at once using the kendo command.

I can make it work for non nested grid. But for nested grid, it will only save the data on the parent row. Was there a workaround for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Saying nested grid, are you talking about hieriarchy grid like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy or something else?

Comment: yes, that's it. now my question is, if ever we made changes to each row details, how can we be able to save those at once. and not by row?

Answer (score 2):

Detail grid is whole new widget inside of parent grid. You have to configure it's `dataSource` with correct transport methods separatly.

Still, if you want to save all grids on your page you can use this function (works perfectly in my project):

```
function SaveAll(){
    $(".k-widget.k-grid").each(function (index, value) {
        var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.sync();
    });
}
```

Or with `saveChanges()` method:

```
function SaveAll(){
    $(".k-widget.k-grid").each(function (index, value) {
        var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
        grid.saveChanges();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still very new to kendogrid. May I ask if where will I place this one? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you have to place it in your own function, and then invoke it eg. on button click event. If you, for example, want it in a grid toolbar you could add it similar like on this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template. You just need to chage script template for something like: `<div class='k-button' onclick='SaveAll()'>Save all</div>` and add my function between `<script></script>` on your page.